# Computer connected to network switch not detected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh

I just got a TP-Link network switch and connected it to my cable modem. One output of the switch goes to my router and the other to and old laptop of mine. However the old laptop does not show on the network map. I used `avahi-discover` from another computer (connected via wireless from the router) and it didn't detect the old laptop. 
One problem is that the old laptop's screen is broken so I can control it only via SSH.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've made some interesting choices regarding your LAN-setup.

If I interpret your question correctly you've connected it like this

```
Modem > Switch > Router > Other Computer (WLAN)
               > Old laptop
```

If it is, indeed, a router you have connected AFTER the switch, and the old laptop connected to the same switch but NOT to the router, I'd say chances are good that the router has a DHCP-server running, handing out IP-addresses to your computers connected to it, but the old laptop is drawing its IP-address from the modem via the switch (which sounds strange, unless the modem has a router part aswell), which in most cases would lead to an IP-conflict.

Why haven't you connected it like this:

```
Modem > Router > Switch > Old Computer
               > Other Computer (WLAN)
```

That's the most common way of connecting things, this way both the laptop and the other computer will connect to the router and let the router handle DHCP and NAT which is how it's usually made.

Comment: Thanks. This is because of the arrangement of the gear around my domicile. The modem and the old laptop are physically close to each other and the router is further away. I can arrange them like you said but then wifi signal strength will decrease (and I can send the switch back!)

Comment: Well, the thing is that in order to get it to work with the current setup you need to do some routing config on the old laptop and so on, it's not plug'n'play the way it's connected now. With the router however, it should be smooth sailing.

Comment: And if you send back the switch, why not buy an Access Point or a range extender instead, to boost the WiFi signal?

Comment: As @JaggenSWE has pointed out, what you're trying to do is going to cause you many problems... the suggested solution will immediately work for you. You may need to purchase some additional equipment to "extend" your wireless network range but this will save you if you have no idea how to configure the routing you'll need if you continue the configuration you currently have.

Comment: Could you refer me to a guide for configuring manually? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say but read up on routing and NAT. Should at least give you a good idea to the job your in for.